# Older oplog entries are not getting truncated

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo instance running with oplogMinRetentionHours set to 24 hours and max oplog size set to 50G. But despite this config settings oplog entries seem to be withhold indefinitely since oplog has entries past 24 hours and oplog size has reached 1.4 TB and .34 TB on disk

**db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1 } ).oplogTruncation.oplogMinRetentionHours**

**24 hrs**

**db.getReplicationInfo()**

```
{
"logSizeMB" : 51200,
"usedMB" : 1464142.51,
"timeDiff" : 3601538,
"timeDiffHours" : 1000.43,
"tFirst" : "Fri Mar 19 2021 14:15:49 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)",
"tLast" : "Fri Apr 30 2021 06:41:27 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)",
"now" : "Fri Apr 30 2021 06:41:28 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"
}
```

**MongoDB server version: 4.4.0**

**OS: Windows Server 2016 DataCenter 64bit**

what I have noticed is event with super user with root role is not able to access **replset.oplogTruncateAfterPoint**, not sure if this is by design

**mongod.log**

> {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T06:35:51.308+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",
> "id":20436,   "ctx":"conn8","msg":"Checking authorization
> failed","attr":{"error":{"code":13,"codeName":"Unauthorized","errmsg":"not
> authorized on local to execute command { aggregate:
> "replset.oplogTruncateAfterPoint", pipeline: [ { $indexStats: {} }
> ], cursor: { batchSize: 1000.0 }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime:
> Timestamp(1619764547, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0,
> 180A28389B6BBA22ACEB5D3517029CFF8D31D3D8), keyId: 6935907196995633156
> } }, $db: "local" }"}}}

Not sure why mongo would not delete older entries from oplog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb oplog truncation seems to be triggered with inserts. So as and when insert happens oplog gets truncated.